# ¿Cuál es el origen del uso de la palabra "codo" como sinónimo de tacaño?

Tags: etimología

Aquí en México utilizamos la palabra codo como sinónimo de tacaño. ¿Cuál es su origen? ¿qué relación tiene con el codo (parte del cuerpo)?

> [codo](http://dle.rae.es/codo), da.
>
> (De codo).
>
> 1. adj. Ec., El Salv., Guat., Hond. y Méx. tacaño (‖ miserable).

Ejemplo:

> Él es tan codo que prefiere irse caminando que tener que pagar camión.

Comment: En Chile no existe la palabra _codo_ con el significado de "tacaño". Es la primera vez que lo leo, nunca lo he escuchado. Lo que sí usamos con mucha frecuencia es _coño_ (sin valor vulgar). Me parece que se debe a que a los inmigrantes españoles en Chile se les dice _coño_ (porque usan esa palabra de muletilla) y por alguna razón histórica se los ha estereotipado como tacaños. "Préstame plata, no seas coño".

Answer (score 9):

Pues encontré [esta liga](http://que-significa.net/la-expresion/codo-cuando-eres-tacano/) que menciona un dato interesante, aunque es probable que haya que tomarlo con un granito de sal.

Parafraseando dice:

> Cuando los ganaderos mexicanos regresaban de Estados Unidos después de
>   vender el ganado para que los ladrones no les quitaran el dinero de la
>   venta confeccionaron una bolsa que escondían al costado del tronco a
>   la altura de las costillas. De esta forma cuando eran asaltados,
>   apretaban los codos para que las monedas no hicieran ruido. Cuando los
>   ladrones se dieron cuenta de la estrategia les decían "afloja el
>   codo".

No sé qué tan cierto sea, pero suena plausible.

Answer (score 4):

Viene de "camina con los codos, para no gastar la suela de los zapatos".

Busque "camina con los codos" en la red y encontrará muchos ejemplos.

Comment: +1 Interesante aunque díficl de imaginar como alguien podría caminar con los codos.

Comment: ;-)   esa es la idea...

Comment: En lugar de decirle a alguien que busque la expresión para confirmarlo, qué tal añadir los enlaces y referencias apropiados en tu respuesta? Además ten en cuenta que favorecemos respuestas que incluyen dicho contenido en lugar de enlazar a otras páginas, para que el contenido quede en este sitio (especialmente si desaparece la pagina enlazada).

Comment: @Diego, de acuerdo, lo editaré. Por ahora, para no olvidar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wM6f2C7YkRI

Answer (score 3):

En Argentina también se da la asociación del codo con la tacañería. Aunque no se usa mucho la palabra como adjetivo o sustantivo en ese sentido, más bien en expresiones como "*tiene el codo de oro/de hierro/duro*", o en ademanes (uno se roza o se señala el codo para expresar que la persona aludida es tacaña).

Creo que tiene que ver con el hecho de que para meter las manos en el bolsillo (para sacar dinero) hace falta doblar los codos. Así, por oposición a la persona dadivosa que lleva las manos al bolsillos fácilmente, se sugiere irónicamente que el tacaño tendría algún problemita físico en el codo que le impide hacerlo...

Algunos también postulan una relación con la palabra "*codicia*", me parece menos probable.